# Plot decision tree doesn't give the expected outcome

Tags: scikit-learn, decision-tree

I have a time series data with (4917, 50, 136) as (batch, step, feature)

There are a total of 8 classes.

I'd like to run a tree decision before I train them with LSTM model to understand the similarities among the classes.

After I fit the tree for an 8-class dataset.

`X_train.shape = (245850, 136)`

`y_train.shape = (245850,)`

I tried to plot a tree but only texts coming out and Jupyter shows that the code is still running.

```
plt.figure(figsize= (15,15))
tree.plot_tree(clf,filled=True,rounded=True)
```

A part of the output is shown below the actual one is way longer.

```
[Text(386.62505751196755, 807.7075471698113, 'X[9] <= 0.214\ngini = 0.825\nsamples = 245850\nvalue = [70000, 44200, 41400, 28350, 23100, 22850, 8750, 7200]'),
 Text(194.71922553590255, 792.322641509434, 'X[8] <= 0.053\ngini = 0.828\nsamples = 202360\nvalue = [54382, 38286, 36102, 22575, 17882, 19248, 7775, 6110]'),
 Text(100.44763452614337, 776.9377358490566, 'X[71] <= -0.421\ngini = 0.824\nsamples = 169238\nvalue = [48221, 31129, 30271, 18167, 14775, 14749, 6717, 5209]'),
 Text(49.35201252001606, 761.5528301886792, 'X[4] <= -0.512\ngini = 0.831\nsamples = 12607\nvalue = [3305, 2125, 1762, 1453, 2254, 898, 423, 387]'),
 Text(18.629607720355484, 746.1679245283019, 'X[69] <= -0.73\ngini = 0.84\nsamples = 5647\nvalue = [1138, 1163, 921, 547, 1014, 459, 179, 226]'),
 Text(4.619141935578377, 730.7830188679245, 'X[0] <= 1.155\ngini = 0.805\nsamples = 1114\nvalue = [320, 193, 134, 75, 271, 62, 38, 21]'),
```

Update

I let the codes ran for long enough time and I got a graph output but it is not right. This confused me as my objective is to have a preliminary examination of the relationships among the classes but this decision tree apparently is not outputting the correct information.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your plot output is correct**. This is the decision tree model you obtained.

If you want to have a more "small" and "simple" decision tree to visualise a preliminary explanation you should tune some hyperparameters of the model.

Concretely, I recommend adjust your `max_depth` to 5, or even less (with this hyperparameter, your tree won't be able to have a depth bigger than that value). As a result, you will obtain a simple model, but you would be able to obtain the basic information you are looking for:

```
dt=DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=5, random_state=42)
```

After that, make the same plot you did.